# Get kubuntu, Mythbuntu,Edubuntu,Xubuntu etc in Ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments

Hey I want best of all worlds and hence I want that i have Kubuntu,edubuntu Xubuntu etc in my ***single*** ubuntu installation can someone please help??

Comment: As in, you want to have the option to run one of these when you login? You can't run all of these at once.

Comment: Yes you got it,I want to have the option to run one of these when I login

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have installed Ubuntu, in a terminal, do

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop xubuntu-desktop mythbuntu-desktop edubuntu-desktop lubuntu-desktop
```

(or install these packages using Software Centre or Synaptic.)

Log out. At the login screen you should be able to choose the desktop environment of your choice. I'm not sure if each of the above corresponds to a different one, though.

Comment: I think that edubuntu and mythubuntu will not have separate DEs. But all the packages from these versions will be available in all the DEs.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop kubuntu-desktop lubuntu-desktop xubuntu-desktop edubuntu-desktop mythbuntu-desktop gnome-shell
```

WARNING: There will be a lot of different programs that have the same purpose.